# What does -vo option in curl mean?

Tags: curl, get

So I have a `curl` request in this format:

```
curl -vo /dev/null domain.com/file.jpg
```

I know this executes a GET request, however I have trouble finding what exactly `-vo` does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [**`man curl`**](http://linux.die.net/man/1/curl):

```
-o, --output <file>
    Write output to <file> instead of stdout. If you are using {} or [] to fetch
    multiple documents, you can use '#' followed by a number in the <file> spec-
    ifier.  That  variable  will be replaced with the current string for the URL
    being fetched. Like in:

        curl http://{one,two}.site.com -o "file_#1.txt"

    [...]


-v, --verbose
    Be more verbose/talkative during the operation.  Useful  for  debugging  and
    seeing  what's  going  on  "under  the hood". A line starting with '>' means
    "header data" sent by curl, '<' means "header data" received by curl that is
    hidden  in  normal cases, and a line starting with '*' means additional info
    provided by curl.

    [...]
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/curl) (`man curl`):

> -o/--output [file]
>
> Write output to [file] instead of stdout. If you are using {} or [] to fetch multiple documents, you can use '#' followed by a number in the [file] specifier. That variable will be replaced with the current string for the URL being fetched. Like in:
> curl http://{one,two}.site.com -o "file_#1.txt"
>
> or use several variables like:
>
> curl http://{site,host}.host[1-5].com -o "#1_#2"
>
> You may use this option as many times as the number of URLs you have.

---

> -v/--verbose
>
> Makes the fetching more verbose/talkative. Mostly useful for debugging. A line starting with '>' means "header data" sent by curl, '<' means "header data" received by curl that is hidden in normal cases, and a line starting with '*' means additional info provided by curl.
> Note that if you only want HTTP headers in the output, -i/--include might be the option you're looking for.
>
> If you think this option still doesn't give you enough details, consider using --trace or --trace-ascii instead.
>
> This option overrides previous uses of --trace-ascii or --trace.